# PostgreSQL Update Column From Lookup

Tags: postgresql, update

I'm trying to replace a column with a lookup from another table.  Seems simple, but I'm thinking `PostgreSQL` is getting in the way for some reason.  I've seen that some syntax that evidently doesn't work in `PostgreSQL`

```
UPDATE A
SET userid = (
SELECT pid FROM B WHERE B.pid = A.userid
)   # => You will need to rewrite or cast the expression (pointing to "(SELECT"
```

I think this `SQL` is valid, and I don't know what I am missing.  How can I get this column to do a simple lookup?

Comment: What datatype is `pid`? What datatype is `userid`? Could the SELECT return more than one row?

Comment: Nope.  Integer vs char(10).

Comment: Not sure about PostgreSQL, but when some DBMSes do implicit conversions, they'll convert the text value to a numeric value (which is always dangerous), instead of converting the numeric value to text. It's safest to make the conversion explicit.

Comment: Ya it was whining about needing a cast, so that did the trick.  The syntax was generally sound, outside of the `from table2` bit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a correct syntax.

```
UPDATE table1 set user_id = table2.user_id from table2 where table1.pid = table2.pid
```

You can also update data from the same table, just *join* the same table with a new alias

```
UPDATE table1 set user_id = (table2.json->>'user_id')::bigint from table1 as table2 where table1.pid = table2.pid
```

Comment: That wasn't working before, but I cast the latter operator as text and it worked fine.  Thank you.